# Angular2 img path

Tags: angular

I have problem to insert image in my app:

Currently I have this:

```
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" routerLinkActive="active">
    <a [routerLink]="['/']">
    <img src="billing.png">Payroll Center
    </a>
    </div>
```

My image is stored in src/app/images/billing.png

I want to call it from admin.component.html which is stored in:
src/app/administration

Comment: Is your problem that the image is not published to dist?  Or that your image path is wrong and should be `<img src="/src/app/images.billing.png">`?

Comment: it is not published, I tried all possible routes to img

Comment: ok - well either you want to move your images outside of your SRC folder and into your publish/dist folder.  OR you will need to add an image copier to your build process.

Comment: They are in dist folder too. If I want to add some image from web via link it is working.

Comment: what is the path of your image in your dist folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presuming you're publishing your image to your dist folder with the same structure as your source, then something like this should work:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" routerLinkActive="active">
    <a [routerLink]="['/']">
        <img src="/app/images/billing.png">Payroll Center
    </a>
</div>
```